# Telebot закрывается после ~10 минут работы

Tags: python, windows, telegram-bot, telebot, azure

Сделал бота на telebot, закинул его на Azure сервер и примерно после 10 минут работы я получаю такую ошибку:

```
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetErro
r(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None,
10054, None))
```

Почему я получаю эту ошибку? Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Проблемы с интернет-соединением. Просто перезапускайте бота.

Answer (score 0):

Я запускаю своего бота вот так:

```
try:
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Это не помогло мне, все равно ошибку получаю

Comment: ну значит действительно проблемы с интернетом,тут уже исключения не помогут